# How can I troubleshoot sharing problems from outside the LAN?

Tags: finder, remote-desktop, network

I'm trying to connect with a server that is not on the same network as my mac, when I enter the ip address the connection doesn't go through. The ip is correct, the server is on, and remote access & login are allowed; I even tried sending the login name i.e afp://ipaddres/shortname. Is there something I am not doing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to set up [port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832156/send-mail-in-background-in-iphone) so that you can connect to your server even though it's behind NAT from your router.

Comment: Is this something you can set from system preferences?

Comment: No, it's a setting on your router.

Comment: http://homepage.mac.com/car1son/static_port_fwd_intro.html will read instructions in link above & see if I can figure something out